# Why does Linux show both more and less memory than I physically have installed?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

I know about swap - this question isn't about that. In dmesg, the Linux (x86-64) kernel tells me this about how much memory I have:

```
[    0.000000] Memory: 3890880k/4915200k available (6073k kernel code, 861160k absent, 163160k reserved, 5015k data, 1596k init)
```

`cat /proc/meminfo` tells me that I have

```
MemTotal:        3910472 kB
```

And by my calculations, I think I should have exactly 4*1024*1024=4194304k RAM. Which is **way** smaller than the second figure in the dmesg line above!

What's with all these different figures?

By the way, `uname -a` outputs:

```
Linux pavilion 3.2.2-1.fc16.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 26 03:21:58 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should read the `dmesg` values "Memory Akb/Bkb available" as:

> There is A available for use right now, and the system's highest page frame number multiplied by the page size is B.

This is from `arch/x86/mm/init_64.c`:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "Memory: %luk/%luk available (%ldk kernel code, "
                 "%ldk absent, %ldk reserved, %ldk data, %ldk init)\n",
                 nr_free_pages() << (PAGE_SHIFT-10),
                 max_pfn << (PAGE_SHIFT-10),
                 codesize >> 10,
                 absent_pages << (PAGE_SHIFT-10),
                 reservedpages << (PAGE_SHIFT-10),
                 datasize >> 10,
                 initsize >> 10);
```

`nr_free_pages()` returns the amount of physical memory, managed by the kernel, that is not currently in use. `max_pfn` is the highest page frame number (the `PAGE_SHIFT` shift converts that to kb). The highest page frame number can be (much) higher than what you could expect - the memory mapping done by the BIOS can contain holes.
How much these holes take up is tracked by the `absent_pages` variable, displayed as `kB absent`. This should explain most of the difference between the second number in the "available" output and your actual, installed RAM.

You can grep for `BIOS-e820` in `dmesg` to "see" these holes. The memory map is displayed there (right at the top of `dmesg` output after boot). You should be able to see at what physical addresses you have real, usable RAM.
(Other x86 quirks and reserved memory areas probably account for the rest - I don't know the details there.)

`MemTotal` in `/proc/meminfo` indicates RAM available for use.  Right at the end of the boot sequence, the kernel frees `init` data it doesn't need any more, so the value reported in `/proc/meminfo` could be a bit higher than what the kernel prints out during the initial parts of the boot sequence.

(`meminfo` uses indirectly `totalram_pages` for that display. For x86_64, this is calculated in `arch/x86/mm/init_64.c` too via `free_all_bootmem()` which itself is in `mm/bootmem.c` for non-NUMA kernels.)