# Server Information

Tags: linux, centos, memory, cpanel

We have just set up a dedicated-server (Linux / Centos7.7 / WHM/Cpanel)
As it is managed by the hosting-company we are not given access to SSH.

Under Server Information in WHM dashboard the info displays as follows:

```
[    0.000000] Memory: 5276136k/17301504k available (7764k kernel code, 552028k absent, 727596k reserved, 5967k data, 1980k init)
```

We just wish to clarify if the server is actually set up with 16GB RAM installed and that it is not being dynamically loaded as this info seems to have changed this the kernel was updated & our server had to be restored

The way we are reading this is that only 5GB out of 16GB is actually available.

We will appreciate some clarity on this :-)

Comment: Here's [a link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30324/why-does-linux-show-both-more-and-less-memory-than-i-physically-have-installed) that explains that message

Comment: Thanks for the link Munzir :) So how can our server only have 5GB RAM available for use out of 16GB RAM?

Comment: @GrantJ This seems to be a question better asked directly to the hosting company.

Answer (score 1):

The 16GB is reported by the BIOS, whereas the 5GB is by the kernel. The kernel might not see all physical memory reported by the BIOS: for instance, the kernel can address only 4 GB of RAM if it has not been compiled with PAE support, even if a larger amount of physical memory is actually available. In your situation, 11GB is unavailable for you to use. Did you pay them for 5GB or 16GB?

Note: Sorry, I should post this as a comment but being new I am not allowed to post comments yet.